# Como validar que clave no existe en base de datos antes de subir XML

Tags: php, sql-server

Quisiera realizar una validación en donde antes de subir el archivo XML se verifique en una tabla de base de datos si el campo `clave` es diferente a lo que se obtiene desde la lectura del XML, si es diferente a lo que contiene la lectura del XML permítalo subir de lo contrario mostrar un mensaje indicando que ya existe la `clave`.

La `clave` inicialmente ya la estoy obteniendo de la lectura de un archivo XML de la siguiente manera:

```
if($res['xml']) {
      
        if( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
          // error_log($errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']]);
          die( $errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']] );
      }
        
      $xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true ); 
      $clave = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Complemento->children('tfd',true)->attributes()['CLAVE'];

include './db/conectar.php';

  if( $conn === false ){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  $sql = "{call ValidarXML(?,?,?)}";

  $params = array($rfc, $total, $factura,);
  $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );
    

      if( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) ){
        $archivoXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
        $rutaXML = "/XML/";

        $filepathXML = $rutaXML.$archivoXML;

        if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $rutaXML . $archivoXML)){
          echo 'Documentos cargados exitosamente';

  }
  else {
          echo 'Error al mover a directorio destino';
        }           
    } else {
        echo 'Por favor verifique el contenido de los documentos';       
    }        
  }
```

La consulta con la que pretendo validar en la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
SELECT CLAVE FROM PURCHASEORDER WHERE CLAVE = ?;
```

Espero que alguien me pueda dar un poco de orientación en esta validación.

**Actualización 1:**

He creado el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en base a los comentarios para comprobar si existe o no existe:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPValidarClave]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CLAVE  VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    /**/
    Declare @Existe int
    if not exists(Select 1 From PURCHASEORDER WHERE CLAVE=@CLAVE)
    begin
        
        set @Existe =1
    end
    else
    begin   
        set @Existe =0
        
    end

    Select @Existe
    /**/
  
END
```

Ya con este procedimiento almacenado hecho solo requiero de la validación desde mi código PHP.

Comment: Jhon !!! Como se supone que quieres validar con esa consulta si algo ya existe ?? Para saber si algo ya existe, seleccionas lo que sea, y validas con el WHERE ... en esa consulta estás agarrando todas las claves de purchaseorder. Solo necesitas validar la que quieres.

Comment: Que es `$result` o de donde viene, puedes agregar esa parte? Si es el resultado de consulta que indicas solo debe agregarle el ` WHERE CLAVE='$clave'` para que filtre lo que desees

Comment: @Excorpion Actualice la pregunta con la condición del WHERE donde agregue la `clave` como parámetro, hace falta algo mas para completar la validación ?

Comment: @F.Igor `$result` viene de un llamado a un procedimiento almacenado donde valido el contenido del XML con los resultados de la tabla en base de datos,

Comment: Piensas incluir esta validacion en el procedimiento `validarXml()`? seria ideal hacerlo ahi enviando el parametro `$clave`. puedes colocar el codigo o la estructura del proc. almacenado?

Comment: @F.Igor Disculpa pero aquí se me paso explicar, la consulta que contiene el procedimiento `validarXml` hace referencia a otra base de datos diferente a la cual tengo que validar la `clave`, si es necesario puedo agregar la estructura del procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? Crea una función donde pases el valor a verificar (`?`). Y dentro de esa función ejecuta un `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM PURCHASEORDER WHERE CLAVE = ?`, verifica la cantidad de filas obtenidas y devuelve `true` si el valor  es mayor que `0` o `false` en caso contrario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es posible que agregues un ejemplo en base a mi código para probarlo y darle validez a tu respuesta

Comment: No tendría problema en hacerlo, pero es que en tu código yo veo una llamada a una SP llamada `ValidarXML` que no se entiende bien qué función tiene. Por eso te preguntaba cuál era el problema en concreto. Porque lo que quieres hacer aquí es tan simple como esto: `function ifExists($param) { //1. Conectar 2. Preparar/ejecutar consulta COUNT 3. Verificar cantidad de filas 4. Si > 0 devuelve true, de lo contrario false }` Y en el contexto: `if (ifExists($param)) { //Existe No subir } else { //No existe, subir archivo }` ¿Intentaste algo así? ¿Qué problemas tienes en tu intento?

Comment: Olvidate del procedimiento almacenado `ValidarXML` ese solo valida la lectura del XML con otra tabla diferente a la que se encuentra el campo `clave `, en este caso es necesario crear un nuevo procedimiento

Comment: @A.Cedano He creado el procedimiento almacenado como me indicaste, ahora solo hace falta la validación desde mi código PHP, podrías apoyarme a completar el resto de la validación ?

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué te empeñas en hacerlo desde un SP cuando puedes hacerlo con un simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` ¿?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126182/discussion-between-john-doe-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes crear una función de validación que reciba en parámetro la clave, verifique si existen registros con esa clave y te devuelva `true` o `false` según el caso.

Todo esto puede hacerse mediante una consulta simple, sin necesidad de usar procedimientos almacenados.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    function isClave($mClave) {
      /*
          Asumimos que la conexión no está en contexto
          y por eso conectamos aquí. 
          Si es un contexto más amplio considera crear una Clase o algo así ...
          Asumimos que este archivo conecta a la BD
          donde quieres verificar la existencia de la clave
      */
      include './db/conectar.php';

      if($conn){
          $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PURCHASEORDER WHERE CLAVE=?";
          if ($stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$mClave))) {
              if ( sqlsrv_execute($stmt) && sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) ) {
                /*
                  La función sólo retornará true cuando encuentre filas
                */
                return true;
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
    }
?>
```

Ahora para llamarla:

```
//...
$clave = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Complemento->children('tfd',true)->attributes()['CLAVE'];

if ( isClave($clave) ) {
    //La clave existe, no hay que subir el archivo
} else {
    //La clave no existe, se sube el archivo
}
```

**Post-Data**: Si tú quieres hacer lo mismo desde una SP solamente tienes que cambiar `$sql` por una llamada a la SP.

Para adaptarlo a la SP que has indicado en tu pregunta, sería más o menos así.

He puesto comentarios en el código explicando las novedades. Si no entiendes algo, pregunta en comentarios.

```
<?php
    function isClave($mClave) {
      /*
          Asumimos que la conexión no está en contexto
          y por eso conectamos aquí. 
          Si es un contexto más amplio considera crear una Clase o algo así ...
          Asumimos que este archivo conecta a la BD
          donde quieres verificar la existencia de la clave
      */
      include './db/conectar.php';

      if($conn){
          /*
            Se pasan dos parámetros porque la SP 
            tiene un parámetro de entrada @CLAVE 
            y uno de salida: el valor 1 o 0 
            Asumo que tu SP no tiene errores y que funciona bien 
          */
          $sql = "{CALL SPValidarClave (?, ?)}";
          #Definimos variable para parámetro de salida
          $mOut=-1;
          $mParams = array(
                            array(&$mClave, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                            array(&$mOut, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
                          );  
          if ($stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $mParams)) {
              if ( sqlsrv_execute($stmt) ) {
                /*
                  La función sólo retornará true cuando 
                  el parámetro de salida de la SP sea igual a 1
                  La salida de la SP estará siempre en la variable $mOut
                */
                return ($mOut == 1);
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Para que se utiliza el & antes del llamado del parámetro dentro del array ?

Comment: @JohnDoe **en PHP se usa `&` para pasar por referencia**. Cuando Microsoft diseño el controlador para PHP decidió que los valores de las consultas preparadas sean pasados por referencia: *Las variables transmitidas como parámetros de consulta se deben pasar por referencia en lugar de por valor. Por ejemplo, se debe transmitir &$myVariable en lugar de $myVariable. Se genera una advertencia de PHP cuando se ejecuta una consulta con parámetros por valor.* ([Más detalles en la doc oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-prepare?view=sql-server-ver15))

Comment: Podías adaptar el código de tu respuesta al código que agregue en mi pregunta inicial ?

Comment: @JohnDoe revisa al final de la respuesta.