# Como almacenar url en un campo de una tabla

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy con un requerimiento nuevo en PHP en el cual estoy intentando almacenar en un campo de una tabla la URL a la que ingresa el usuario una vez ingresa con sus respectivas credenciales. La manera en que estoy intentando obtener la URL en la cual ingresa el usuario es la siguiente:

```
  $host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
  $url= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  echo "http://" . $host . $url;
```

Con la sentencia anterior he logrado obtener la URL a la cual ingresa el usuario, ahora lo que requiero es almacenar esto en el campo que he creado en mi tabla.

Para el ingreso del usuario he preparado un procedimiento almacenado donde valida sus credenciales  `username` y `password` además de almacenar la hora de ultimo acceso. El procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidarCredenciales]
    @USER VARCHAR(20),
    @PASS VARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @ULTIMOACCESO DATETIME
    
    SELECT @ULTIMOACCESO = 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN U.ULTIMOACCESO = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN GETDATE()
                                ELSE U.ULTIMOACCESO
                            END
    FROM USUARIOS U
    WHERE 
        U.USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

        
    UPDATE USUARIOS
        SET ULTIMOACCESO = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT @ULTIMOACCESO ACCESO, INSERTED.*      
        WHERE 
            USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            
END
```

La estructura de mi tabla `USUARIOS` es la siguiente, donde la columna `URL` es en donde deseo almacenar la respectiva URL a la que ingresa el usuario.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USUARIOS](
    [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ULTIMOACCESO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [USUARIO] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [TIPOUSUARIO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
)
```

Desde PHP tengo el siguiente llamado al procedimiento almacenado y a las respectivas validaciones del `USER` y `PASS`:

```
            $USER = $_POST['username'];
            $PASS = $_POST['password'];
            $query = array();
            include './db/connect.php';
            $sql = "{call ValidarCredenciales(?,?)}";
            $params = array($USER ,$PASS);
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
            if ( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }   
            session_start();
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $record = array(
                    "usuario"   => utf8_encode($row['USUARIO']),
                    "nombre"    => utf8_encode($row['NOMBRE']),
                    "ultimoacceso" => $row['ACCESO'],
                    "tipoproveedor" => $row['TIPOPROVEEDOR'],                   
                    );
                        
                array_push($query, $record);                
            }
            $size = sizeof($query);
            if($size != 0){
                $_SESSION["acceso"] = time();               
            }

            $_SESSION['validacion'] = $query;
            
            echo json_encode($_SESSION['validacion']);
            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Agradezco quien me pueda apoyar en poder almacenar la URL en el campo que mencione anteriormente.

**Actualización 1:**

He intentado lo siguiente, primero he pasado el parámetro de la url cuando llamo el proceso `UPDATE USUARIOS SET URL= @url` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidarCredenciales]
    @USER VARCHAR(20),
    @PASS VARCHAR(20),
    @URL VARCHAR(max)
 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @ULTIMOACCESO DATETIME
    
    SELECT @ULTIMOACCESO = 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN U.ULTIMOACCESO = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN GETDATE()
                                ELSE U.ULTIMOACCESO
                            END
    FROM USUARIOS U
    WHERE 
        U.USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

        
    UPDATE USUARIOS
        SET ULTIMOACCESO = GETDATE(),
            URL=@URL
    OUTPUT @ULTIMOACCESO ACCESO, INSERTED.*      
        WHERE 
            USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            
END
```

Y luego adicional a esto he agregado un tercer parámetro en el llamado del procedimiento almacenado desde PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "{call ValidarCredenciales(?,?,?)}";
```

Al momento de querer iniciar sesión con las respectivas credenciales he obtenido lo siguiente como error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07002
            [SQLSTATE] => 07002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
        )

)
```

No se si hace falta algo mas en mi procedimiento almacenado o algo mas desde mi código PHP

Comment: seria hacer un update y añadirlo al user?

Comment: @steven Es correcto, es lo que requiero hacer

Comment: pasar el parámetro de la url cuando llamas el procesos  UPDATE USUARIOS  SET  URL= @url ,

Comment: @steven Podrías aportarme un ejemplo como respuesta en base a mi pregunta para darle validez a tu respuesta.

Comment: En la SP olvidaste agregar una coma, cuando creaste el tercer parámetro, aquí: `@PASS VARCHAR(20) ****debe ir una coma aquí**** @URL VARCHAR(max)` debes corregirlo de este modo: `@PASS VARCHAR(20), @URL VARCHAR(max)`

Comment: @A.Cedano Se agrego la coma pero igual sigue mostrando el mismo error, alguna otra sugerencia ? crees que haga falta algo en mi código PHP ?

Comment: ¿Probaste esa SP directamente en el SGBD? Conviene siempre probar este tipo de código y depurar los errores de sintanxis en el gestor de base de datos, así no andas rompiéndote el coco. Si allí funciona entonces quedará claro que algo anda mal en PHP, pero lo que parece haber es un error de sintaxis en tu SP.

Comment: Y, actualiza el código PHP en tu pregunta, en el código actual falta un parámetro en la llamada a la SP y además no debes usar `sqlsrv_query()` en consultas preparadas, sino `sqlsrv_prepare()`  y debes indicar si los parámetros que pasas son del tipo IN, OUT o INOUT ¿? Eso no queda claro en tu SP, no soy experto en SQL Server y me cuesta descifrar en tu SP de qué tipo son los parámetros que la misma maneja, ¿podrías aclarar eso para escribirte una respuesta en cuanto al código PHP que debes implementar?

Comment: No sé si eres el mismo (pues creo hay varios usarios llamados Jhon Doe), pero [en esta respuesta (último bloque de código)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/460089/29967) creo que está claramente explicado el asunto de los parámetros y cómo se pasan desde PHP. En aquel caso la SP tenía parámetros de entrada y de salida.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidarCredenciales]
    @USER VARCHAR(20),
    @PASS VARCHAR(20)
    @URL VARCHAR(max)
 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @ULTIMOACCESO DATETIME
    
    SELECT @ULTIMOACCESO = 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN U.ULTIMOACCESO = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN GETDATE()
                                ELSE U.ULTIMOACCESO
                            END
    FROM USUARIOS U
    WHERE 
        U.USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

        
    UPDATE USUARIOS
        SET ULTIMOACCESO = GETDATE(),
            URL=@URL
    OUTPUT @ULTIMOACCESO ACCESO, INSERTED.*      
        WHERE 
            USUARIO = @USER COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            AND PASSWORD = @PASS COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            
END
```

Comment: Ok, y en PHP no tengo que asignarle un valor a esa variable ? o ya no tengo que cambiar nada en mi código PHP ?

Comment: $sql = "{call ValidarCredenciales(?,?,?)}";

Comment: He realizado lo que indicaste pero he obtenido un error al momento de ingresar con las credenciales, hace falta algo mas que deba agregar en mi código PHP ?

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una descripción clara de lo que hacen o cómo funcionan no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios y se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más información. Lee [answer] para aprender más sobre cómo mejorar tus respuestas.